# how to find the modulus of a complex number without multiplying them out into cartesian form?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know $\mid z\mid=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ where $z=a+bi$, but how do I solve for the modulus of $\frac{1-4i}{6+5i}$ without multiplying them out into cartesian form?

Comment: Hint: use the property $|z_1/z_2|=|z_1|/|z_2|$.

Comment: Well $|\frac zw| = \frac {|z|}{|w|}$ so you have $|z| =\frac {\sqrt {17}}{\sqrt{61}}$.